# How to deploy lumen framework on shared hosting (subdomain)

Tags: php, hosting, lumen

I have project on localhost and I Need someone can help me to deploy lumen framework to hosting, i have been search in google for deploy lumen but i just found deploy laravel, maybe laravel and lumen is the same framework but i don't know how to deploy the lumen framework to my shared hosting in subdomain.

I have be been upload to :

```
/home/usernamecpanel/lumen
```

and public folder i put to my subdomain like

```
/home/usernamecpanel/public_html/subdomain/index.php 
/home/usernamecpanel/public_html/subdomain/.htaccess
```

but i just got error 500.

oh, before i run i have been edit index.php to directing to lumenproject :

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../../lumen/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I really confuse and i have been search in few day but cannot found the solution, i think someone can help me.

thank you.

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I not got any answer from stackoverflow, and doesn't one onswer my question in stackoverflow, so i try hard find own solution with manual upload my lumen application in my shared hosting.

just put your lumen application in outside public_html and put your index.php file to subdomain and edit index.php set route to your subdomain.

if anyone have problem like me and read this question, you can ask from this question, i will help you if i got notice from this page.

Comment: where do you get the `index.php`?

Comment: put all your index.php in your sub domain and change your project link to your subdomain

Answer (score 17):

Thanks for reviewing my edit

**How to Fix it?**

1. Zipping your Lumen Project
2. Go to your shared hosting file manager
3. I assume your shared hosting file manager have this directory structure like `/home/username/public_html`.
4. Create a folder outside public_html or htdocs, the folder name is up to you, example "myfolder" the structure looks like `/home/username/myfolder`
5. Upload your project to the new folder you have been created and unzip.
6. After unzip, inside the "myfolder" there is a folder named "public", move the contents inside to

**For Main Domain**

`/home/username/public_html`

**For Subdomain or Subfolder**

`/home/username/public_html/sub`

7. After moving those files, edit the `index.php` inside `/home/username/public_html` or `/home/username/public_html/sub`
8. Inside the file you see this code

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

change the code to

**For Main Domain**

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../myfolder/bootstrap/app.php';`

**For Sub Domain/Subfolder**

`$app = require __DIR__.'/../../myfolder/bootstrap/app.php';`

**Don't forget** to edit the APP_URL in `.env` file inside "myfolder"

Example the APP_URL `.env` file

```
APP_URL=http://yourdomain.com or http://sub.yourdomain.com or http://yourdomain.com/sub
```

Comment: This post is absolute gold and should be updated as the accepted answer. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move it with FileZilla to a subfolder inside `/var/www/html/foldername` and set configuration to the directory, but I wouldn't recommend you to set up a Micro Service in Shared host.

Comment: move 'it' you mean where ? and how to config it ? why not recommend ? and what your recommend ? please tell me, thanks.

Comment: i still got error after move my project to /var/www/html/foldername message  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/username/var/www/html/lumen/vendor/illuminate/config/Repository.php on line 68

Comment: The main reason why you don't want to deploy a lumen application in a shared host is that you have no access to the terminal. of course, you can lumen has limited artisan commands, but you want to redirect your website to `app/lumen/index.php`

Comment: In shared host, what you can do is, move `index.php` to `public_html` and edit `$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php;`
` to `$app = require __DIR__.'/../lumen/bootstrap/app.php';`, note that because you don't have much control over the server, this is a workaround, there are other solutions too, but this is how I used to set my applications up.

Comment: I do, but why still cannot running ?